# Браузер не видит открывающий тег

Tags: html

В этом коде браузер и валидатор пропускают открывающий тег < p >

< p >
    < h3 >< i >Сколько стоит обучение?< /i >< /h3 >
    < br >
    &rarr;   Обучение совершенно БЕСПЛАТНОЕ!
< /p >

Кто нибудь знает почему?

Answer (score 1):

из-за того, что тег h3 - блочный, неправильно интерпретируется ваш код. вы внутри блочного еще блочный размещаете. смотрите в панель разработчиков, что он вам генерирует.

```
<p></p>
<h3><i>Сколько стоит обучение?</i></h3>
<br>
→ Обучение совершенно БЕСПЛАТНОЕ!
<p></p>
```

поэтому я думаю валидатор и ругается

Comment: вы были правы))
так и не разобрался чем ему не нравится H3
сделал проще , заменил его на span и прописал стили как у H3

Comment: =) учитываете в  будущем, что в параграфе строчный текст и все же заголовки лучше делать заголовками. но так тоже очень даже ничего.

Comment: у меня идет больше не заголовками, а просто выделение вопроса)))
ну для простоты взял H3
ну теперь буду знать))))
спасибо большое))